# Select a Gregorian date and display the equivalent hebrew date

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, telerik, raddatepicker

Created a RadDatePicker in this way:

**XAML**:

```
 <telerikInput:RadDatePicker x:Name="TelerikDatePicker"
     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
     VerticalAlignment="Center"
     Width="300" >
 </telerikInput:RadDatePicker>
```

and **C#:**

```
 var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "he-IL" );
 cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new HebrewCalendar();
 TelerikDatePicker.Culture = cultureInfo;
```

The behavior is shown in the attached 2 screenshots (Select a date in the Hebrew calendar and display the result as the equivalent Gregorian date):

I would like to do the opposite behavior, i.e. to have the user select a Gregorian date and display the result as the equivalent Hebrew date.

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Eitan

[image: Select Hebrew Date]

[image: Gregorian equivalent date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer I got from Telerik:

"Following the Microsoft standards the RadDatePicker control gets the CultureInfo of the current thread, so it is not possible to have RadDatePickers with different calendars on one page."